# How to get a grid row count with Selenium in C#?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, test-strategy

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get the count of how many `rows` are displaying in an `HTML Grid` on a page.

From researching several stack exchanges some people reference `GetXPathCount`, but my compiler does not recognize this command nor can I find search results for a name space to make it work.

Preferably I would like to use something using `By.Id` or `By.CssSelector`.

Could anyone assist me in a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that was entered by Brandon Garlock won't work for C# which you included in your tags, here is the C# version to help with the row count:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='yourIDhere']//tr")).Count;
```

Also be aware that if you have a grid header row, you will want to filter that out so it doesn't throw off your count.

Comment: I was skeptical when i saw .size because its used to get height and width dimensions. Thanks will try this.

Comment: This does work and imo now that i have more experience is the best way to perform said task.

Comment: xpath is missing a closing ]: "//table[@id='yourIDhere']//tr" instead of "//table[@id='yourIDhere'//tr"

Comment: @07FwqiRQT you are quite right, that change is reflected