# Getting row count of HTML table always returns 1?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I wish to grab an `HTML` table and extract the number of rows it has. I stumbled upon a solution linked here [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/13308/36161). However, the proposed solution always returns row count of 1. I've alswo tried the `IList<IWebElement>` approach to get the length, but the result is the same. My table structure is pretty straightforward. Table's `HTML` is below.

How to get the total number of `<tr>`'s?

```
<table id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable" class="dxgvTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" onclick="ASPx.GTableClick('splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea', event);" ondblclick="ASPx.GVTableDblClick('splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea', event);" oncontextmenu="return ASPx.GVContextMenu('splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea',event);" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;empty-cells:show;table-layout:fixed;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
<tbody>
    <tr class="dxgvArm">
        <td style="width:28px;"></td>
        <td style="width:200px;"></td>
        <td style="width:210px;"></td>
        <td style="width:180px;"></td>
        <td style="width:100px;"></td>
        <td style="width:250px;"></td>
        <td style="width:180px;"></td>
        <td style="width:180px;"></td>
        <td style="width:180px;"></td>
        <td style="width:150px;"></td>
        <td style="width:170px;"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXDataRow0" class="dxgvDataRow" style="">
        <td id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_tccell0_0" class="dxgv" align="center" style="vertical-align:Middle;">
            <img src="/Client/images/7.jpg" alt="" width="14px" height="16px">
        </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">12/19/2018 12:05:24 PM</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Osa test</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv" align="right">28</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">.txt</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Selenium test</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Normalno</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dxgvHEC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXDataRow1" class="dxgvDataRow" style="">
        <td id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_tccell1_0" class="dxgv" align="center" style="vertical-align:Middle;">
            <img src="/Client/images/9.jpg" alt="" width="14px" height="16px">
        </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">12/17/2018 1:55:45 PM</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Osa test</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv" align="right">22</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">.txt</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">d1</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">petar </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Normalno</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dxgvHEC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXDataRow2" class="dxgvDataRow" style="">
        <td id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_tccell2_0" class="dxgv" align="center" style="vertical-align:Middle;">
            <img src="/Client/images/7.jpg" alt="" width="14px" height="16px">
        </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">12/14/2018 1:08:38 PM</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Osa test</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv" align="right">16</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">.txt</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">asdf</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">petar </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Normalno</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dxgvHEC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXDataRow3" class="dxgvDataRow" style="">
        <td id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_tccell3_0" class="dxgv" align="center" style="vertical-align:Middle;">
            <img src="/Client/images/7.jpg" alt="" width="14px" height="16px">
        </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">12/14/2018 1:03:33 PM</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Osa test</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv" align="right">19</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">.txt</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">bnmbnm</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">petar </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Normalno</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dxgvHEC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXDataRow4" class="dxgvDataRow" style="">
        <td id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_tccell4_0" class="dxgv" align="center" style="vertical-align:Middle;">
            <img src="/Client/images/7.jpg" alt="" width="14px" height="16px">
        </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">12/14/2018 12:48:38 PM</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Osa test</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv" align="right">18</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">.txt</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">vcxv</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">petar </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Normalno</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dxgvHEC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXDataRow5" class="dxgvDataRow" style="">
        <td id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_tccell5_0" class="dxgv" align="center" style="vertical-align:Middle;">
            <img src="/Client/images/7.jpg" alt="" width="14px" height="16px">
        </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">12/14/2018 12:40:11 PM</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Osa test</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv" align="right">21</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">.txt</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">gfdg</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">petar </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Normalno</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">ealo</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dxgvHEC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXDataRow6" class="dxgvDataRow" style="">
        <td id="splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_tccell6_0" class="dxgv" align="center" style="vertical-align:Middle;">
            <img src="/Client/images/1.jpg" alt="" width="14px" height="16px">
        </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">12/7/2018 3:10:17 PM</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Osa test</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv" align="right">15</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">.txt</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">petar </td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">Normalno</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dx-nowrap dxgv">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="dxgvHEC"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
int rowCount = Driver
    .chrome
    .FindElements(
        By.XPath("//[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]"))
            .Count();

var rowCount1 = Driver
    .chrome
    .FindElements
        (By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]/tbody"))
            .Count();

IList <IWebElement> table = Driver
    .chrome
    .FindElements(
         By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]"));
```

Comment: can you show what you've tried

Comment: i have updated my answer check out it is accordingly the link you reffered

Comment: So far, I've tried these approaches:

`int rowCount = Driver.chrome.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]")).Count();`<br/>
`var rowCount1 = Driver.chrome.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]/tbody")).Count();` <br/> 

`IList <IWebElement> table = Driver.chrome.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]"));`

Comment: this is because your `xpath` is till table and there is only 1 table so count will be 1 only

Comment: copy path till tr

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, so I tried several things:
`int rowCount = Driver.chrome.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]")).Count();`

           `var rowCount1 = Driver.chrome.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]/tbody")).Count();`

            `var rowCount2 = Driver.chrome.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]")).Count();`

Al three return 1.

Comment: what i mean is your count was never for rows it was limited to either table or tbody

Comment: so i suggest you that get `xpath` table/tbody/tr

Comment: var rowCount2 = Driver.chrome.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable\"]/tbody/tr")).Count();`

Al three return `count()`.

Comment: this [post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13305/how-to-get-a-grid-row-count-with-selenium-in-c/13308#13308) that you inspired from has a typo: "//table[@id='yourIDhere'//tr" is missing a closing ]. It should be "//table[@id='yourIDhere']//tr"

Comment: It's this one: 

`driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='myTableId']//tr")).Count()`

Row count is correct. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
var table = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
foreach (var row in rows)
{
  Console.WriteLine(row);       
}
```

and as your link

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='splitter_callbackWorkAreaPanel_workAreaUC_gvAdminArea_DXMainTable'//tbody//tr")).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you have tried I see you did not count the number of rows, but a number of tables instead, that is why you always got `1` out of it.

To get the row count you can do as simple as this:

```
int rowCount = Driver
    .chrome
    .FindElements(
         By.CssSelector("table[class='dxgvTable'] tr")).Count();
```

`tr` is `table row` in html, so that is what you should be looking for.